# RecyclerView: weird layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I reduced my item view to the bare minimum but I still have a layout with a lot of padding and that's not what I expected.

See the photo:

One cell in the renderer:

[image: one cell]

The actual view:

[image]

Can someone explain how I can remove these white spaces on the top and the bottom of the image?

Here is the code (very straightforward):

**One cell**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/categoryPhoto"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/bg_alles_fur_kinder" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/categoryName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Children"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/categoryPhoto"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/categoryPhoto"
                android:textSize="22sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**The custom RecyclerView**

```
/**
 * Created by laurentmeyer on 21/08/16.
 */
public class CategoryRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {

    public CategoryRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setHasFixedSize(true);
        ArrayList<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>();
        categories.add(new Category(Category.CategoryType.CHILDREN));
        categories.add(new Category(Category.CategoryType.DECORATION));
        categories.add(new Category(Category.CategoryType.FASHION));
        categories.add(new Category(Category.CategoryType.FURNITURE));
        categories.add(new Category(Category.CategoryType.HOUSE));
        categories.add(new Category(Category.CategoryType.LITTERATURE));
        categories.add(new Category(Category.CategoryType.MULTIMEDIA));
        categories.add(new Category(Category.CategoryType.OTHER));
        CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter(categories);
        setAdapter(adapter);
        GridLayoutManager glm = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);
        glm.setAutoMeasureEnabled(true);
        setLayoutManager(glm);
    }

    public class CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter.CategoryViewHolder> {

        List<Category> categories;

        CategoryRecyclerViewAdapter(List<Category> categories) {
            this.categories = categories;
        }


        @Override
        public CategoryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.category_card, parent, false);
            CategoryViewHolder cvh = new CategoryViewHolder(v);
            return cvh;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(CategoryViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.categoryName.setText(categories.get(position).getType().getName());
            holder.photo.setImageResource(categories.get(position).getType().imageId);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
            super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        }


        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return categories.size();
        }

        public class CategoryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            TextView categoryName;
            ImageView photo;


            public CategoryViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                categoryName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoryName);
                photo = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoryPhoto);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

**EDIT**: Using a `LinearLayoutManager` works perfectly.

Comment: Do you really need to nest a RelativeLayout in a LinearLayout? Nested layouts are bad for performances.

Comment: Ok yeah, I can remove that, there was a cardview before, but I removed it for the debug. Thx

Comment: Now search carefully your current theme/style for paddings/marginns and possibly what's hidden in the `dimens.xml` file.

Comment: Nope set all to zero, changing nothing

Comment: it seems like image is getting rescaled to fit automatically into the cell. try using a `scale type` attribute in the image view tag of xml.

Comment: @SaranSankaran that would work but that's not the expected behaviour, see my answer

Comment: `set all to zero, changing nothing` I changed mine to negative values, instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I GOT IT!

If you use: `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` in the `ImageView` it works!

Credits to: [AppGuruz](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/learn-recyclerview-with-an-example-in-android)

Comment: Great. Now please accept you own answer, in order to remove your post from the Unanswered Question Queue.